# Virtus: distinguish empty arrays from an unset attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several forms that submit to a Virtus object (through a controller). Some forms contain an `extras` attribute, others don't.

I currently can't distinguish whether `extras` has been set to an empty array (i.e. the user deselects all checkboxes on the form) or whether extras has never been submitted. In either case, `extras` will be an empty array.

I need this distinction because if the user deselects all `extras` I need to update them. On the other hand, if extras were not part of the form (i.e. not in the params), I shouldn't update them.

```
class UpdateForm
  include Virtus.model(nullify_blank: true)
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attribute :extras, Array
  attribute :booking_time, Time

  def save
    updatable_attributes = self.attributes.delete_if { |key, value| value.blank? }
    some_object.update(updatable_attributes)
  end
end
```

How can I make Virtus to give me a nil on `extras` if I call it like this:

```
UpdateForm.new(booking_time: Time.current)
```

Or is there a better pattern to do this?

Comment: `blank?` returns true for empties. Use `value.nil?` instead (maybe for this particular attribute.)

Comment: The thing is, `:extras` will be converted to an empty array if it was't set, so `value.nil?` won't help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `@extras` attribute will be set to an empty array (even if you [add](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#default-values) `default: nil` to the attribute).
What you can do is to override initializer so it will set `@extras` to `nil` unless it was actually defined.
And use `#nil?` instead of `#blank?` which returns true on empty array.

```
class UpdateForm
  include Virtus.model(nullify_blank: true)
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attribute :extras, Array
  attribute :booking_time, Time

  def initialize(opts={})
    super
    @extras = nil unless (opts[:extras] || opts['extras'])
  end

  def save
    updatable_attributes = self.attributes.delete_if { |key, value| value.nil? }
    some_object.update(updatable_attributes)
  end
end
```